# How can I provide Advanced custom searching in a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search

I have one requirement to provide advance searching capabilities where the user will retrieve documents on basis of certain search parameters. For example a user selects a category, few sub-categories and few tags. Such as a user selects 
**Category**:- upper-wear
**Sub-Category**:- Shirts and T-Shirts(could be multiple) 
**Tags** :- Cotton, Woolen and Denim.

Then the search should happen based on these pre-selected parameters and results should be retrieved accordingly.

This should look somewhat similar to this:-

[image: advance search]

Please help! Any help would be much appreciated and will save me a lot of time.